# Javascript angle direction

Tags: javascript, direction, angle

Simple javascript angle question:

Which direction do angles go in in javascript?

Is it:

```
   90
180    0
   270
```

or

```
   270
180    0
   90
```

or something else?

I'm aware that javascript uses radians, I used degrees for illustraion.

Comment: Are you using some library or framework? If all you are using are the basic math functions (sine, cosine, tangent, etc) the coordinate system doesn't matter and you can point it in whatever direction you want.

Answer (score 3):

On a regular unit circle, the *y* axis points up, so the angles increase counter-clockwise:

[image]

But in an HTML document, or the canvas element, the *y* axis points down, so if you increase the angle *t* and plot points on *x, y* with *cos(t)*, *sin(t)*, the result will be clockwise:

```
       270
 180          0
       90
```

([Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/dUntf/))

As the other answers say, that's not because of how angles work in JavaScript, but because of how the coordinate space is oriented.

Answer (score 0):

It will likely depend upon the javascript library you're using.

However, for the most part degrees of rotation are relative to the original position. So rotating 180 degrees will always turn the image (or whatever) upside down, otherwise elements would require knowledge of, what I shall term, 'up-ness' (which way is the up orientation) of itself.

Answer (score 0):

An angle by definition has no direction, but is rather the measure of the radial distance between two intersecting lines.

Various libraries/css methods might measure the angle from a certain direction - like up for example, but this totally depends on the context.

Javascript itself has no concept of directions to angles - it is something that has to be built on top of javascript's angle functions.

Comment: OK, so I didn't phrase my question explicitly. Let's say I have an angle, which in degrees is 90, then I add 40 degrees, will this be clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Comment: I think your question is clear, and the answer is, that javascript has some functions to calculate angles, but an angle has no inherent direction - so javascript does not have the concept of a direction for it's angles. If two angle in a triangle add up to 170˚ for example, the third will be 10˚ - and there is no direction attached to any of them. This is how javascript's implementation of angles work.

Comment: If you have 90˚, and add 40˚, you will end up with 130˚, and there is no direction ascribed to that - it is just a 130˚ wide angle. If you have a line, say for example pointing vertically, and another line that is 130˚ from that, the second line will be rotated 130˚ clockwise - but this is not a javascript thing, this is more a convention thing, and handled by whatever system you are using for rendering.